# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) style.css

Tags: html, filezilla

I need some help, I am making a web page for my HTML class and in my text editor when I run the program in chrome everything looks fine and styled, but when I upload the html file to the server in filezilla and then search it in chrome there is no style to it just words. Here is my code

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"
```

When I open the developer tools in the page online it brings me the message

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) style.css

Thats the code to style the page so I was wondering if something was wrong with the code? That its not finding the style.css? Or am I supposed to include the style sheet file into the server with filezilla? I am just stuck and I need some help

[here is the link to the website](http://apppdwebcis.fvtc.edu/300010647/pizzaindex.html)

Comment: What does the directory look like?

Comment: I am seeing the CSS on the website.

Answer (score 0):

Upload both your style sheet with your html file into the same server.

Comment: I just did that and it brings me back to the same screen but now the error says "pizzaindex.html:7 GET http://apppdwebcis.fvtc.edu/300010647/css/style.css" What does this mean?

Comment: May be you make a error path, I can access to this path: http://apppdwebcis.fvtc.edu/300010647/style.css. If you add the `css/` to the path, you need to upload the style sheet file to the `css` directory in the server

Comment: Okay so i have the style up now, but now there arent pictures where i need them to be  http://apppdwebcis.fvtc.edu/300010647/pizzaindex.html . It also now says Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) bodyBg.png and featureBg.png those are the pictures i need in the webpage

Comment: its just that you need to upload them to the same server and fix the path that it is referencing in your HTML

Comment: First check the path and upload the images to the server. If you access for 'img/a.png', you should have the image in `img/a.png` in the server.All resources follow the same theory.

Comment: Okay, how would I fix the path that is referencing? fix this one href="css/style.css"?

Comment: http://apppdwebcis.fvtc.edu/300010647/featureBg.png http://apppdwebcis.fvtc.edu/300010647/bodyBg.png those are the pictures i need in my webpage

Comment: You didn't show any source. I will look at it in a minute

Comment: You didn't put any image in the html. of course the files won't be there.

Comment: Well how do i do that?

Comment: You link to the <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">,and I can access to the images in http://apppdwebcis.fvtc.edu/300010647/bodyBg.png,  so the style.css and the img is in the same directory `300010647/` , so in the style.css. You need to using images through `./bodyBg.png`, not `../img/bodyBg.png`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it can be the issue of './', Try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
```

Comment: I actually checked it, The link you mentioned isn't showing any error related to style.css

Answer (score 0):

Your `style.css` working fine. The problem persists with image loading.

Currently your background path like this: `background: url('../img/featureBG.png') no-repeat;`

You change this path as: `background: url('featureBG.png') no-repeat;` then its work fine.